# Alternate line alignment, is it possible?

Tags: align

I want the equations to be aligned, and the "for blah" parts to be left justified. I have tried using align, but to have the equations and "for blah" parts in separate columns gives a bad box. Help?

[picture of what I want to typeset http://goo.gl/6CfjPa](http://goo.gl/6CfjPa)

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Answer (score 2):

Use `\intertext`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
  \begin{align*}
    \intertext{For bal bla $x < 0$, $y>0$}
    x &= y + z\\
    \intertext{For bal bla}
    y&= a + b
  \end{align*}
\end{document}
```

Or `\shortintertext` which needs `mathtools`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\begin{document}
  \begin{align*}
    \shortintertext{For bal bla $x < 0$, $y>0$}
    x &= y + z\\
    \shortintertext{For bal bla}
    y&= a + b
  \end{align*}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @Megan you are welcome. Please don't forget to upvote (after you get 15 rep points) and accept the useful answer (by clicking the green check mark next to it). This is the customary way of saying thanks here. For details please see: [How do you accept an answer](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1852/how-do-you-accept-an-answer)